# Show that the ideal generated by $5$ and $1 - 8i$ is a principal ideal in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ of Gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I don't see how $(5, 1 - 8i)$ would generate the element $5$. I think that $5$ and $1 - 8i$ would have to have a common factor but I can't find any that divide both.

Comment: $5$ is *in* $(5, 1-8i)$.

Comment: In what sense generate? $5=1\cdot 5+0\cdot(1-8i)$.

Comment: $5=(1+2i)(1-2i)$

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know whether that's even going in the right direction. In order for the ideal (5, 1 - 8i) to be principal don't both those elements have to be generated by a single element in Z[i]?

Answer (score 8):

The prime factors of $5$ are $1+2i$ and $1-2i$ while the prime factors of $1-8i$ are $1+2i$ and $3+2i$. Therefore the GCD of $5$ and $1-8i$ is $1+2i$, or, in the language of ideals, we have $(5, 1-8i)=(1+2i)$.

More abstractly, you can prove that *any* ideal in the Gaussian integers must be principal, by using the Euclidean algorithm.

You can also use the Euclidean algorithm to find the GCD of the two Gaussian integers. First compute:

$$\frac{1-8i}{5} = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{-8}{5}i$$
and round each part to the nearest integer to get the quotient $-2i$.

So the first step gives
$$1-8i = -2i(5) + (1+2i).
$$
In the next step we find $5=(1-2i)(1+2i)+0$ so $1+2i$ is the GCD of $5$ and $1-8i$. This is probably the simplest way.

Answer (score 3):

I think I may understand the question. We want to see that $(5,1-8i)$ is principal. We see that $5=(1+2i)(1-2i)$ and $1-8i=(1+2i)(3+2i)$, and so $(5,1-8i)=(1+2i)$, since this is the greatest common divisor of $5$ and $1-8i$.

Comment: To pick nits just a little: this appears to implicitly use the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a unique factorization domain—otherwise it only shows that $(5,1-8i)\subset(1+2i)$.  To avoid using this fact, we should show that $1$ is a linear combination of $1-2i$ and $3+2i$, which, together with what you've written, implies that $(1+2i) \subset (5,1-8i)$.

Comment: Yes, you are right.